# Need to copy remotely hosted file via Shell Command

Tags: file, shell, copy, command

There is a file that hosted remotely on a server that is not supporting Shell Access. I bought a new server that supports Shell Access so now I want to copy a file that is on the non-supporting server to new server via a Shell Command using Putty.

The file URL is like this `http://www.domain.com/file.gzip` and it is username/password protected.

To be more specific, I want to copy a backup of a home directory from cPanel to my new server via Shell command. I have done this few months ago but I don't remember it now and also I failed to Google it.

Comment: What do you mean by "username/password" protected? Some kind of log in form or normal HTTP authentication?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Thank all for the help and trying to help. Eren Yagdiran gave the exact solution that I am looking and I used before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use wget ?
so you can download your files to your new server.?

$ wget --user='userhere' --password='myPassword' http://youroldhost/backup.zip